# Tensorboard won't display anything

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to learn to use tensorboard. I figured I'd start with some simple test code:

```
x = tf.truncated_normal([32,1])
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10,32]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10,1]))
xw = tf.matmul(w1,x)
logits = xw + b
summary = tf.summary.tensor_summary('logits',logits)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs',sess.graph)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([init])
    logits = sess.run(logits)
    add_summary = sess.run(summary)
    writer.add_summary(add_summary)
    writer.close()
```

but the page at http://0.0.0.0:6006/ just tells me that "no scalar/histogram/etc data was found" no matter what I do. The program is writing event files to the log folder, and I'm pretty sure that I'm giving tensorboard the filepath that leads to the logs. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Your code does not compile. `sess` (in `sess.graph`) is undefined. So yes, there is something wrong. I got tensorboard to work and show me the graph when I moved that `writer` statement down into the `with`, but I didn't get it to display a histogram. However I didn't get your error message either.